# Javascript - only select a certain pattern in a string

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to extract a string from a tag in javascript by using :

`document.querySelector('.title h2').textContent`

But I get something like this (double quotes included) :

> "(lots of spaces) String stuff (lots of spaces)"

and I actually need to retrieve only the text part (String stuff in this example) in the string, lefting behind the double quotes and the spaces.

I know I'll need some regex, but I don't know how to proceed in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using trim method for string.

```
var a = "    String stuff    ";
console.log(a.trim());       // Prints: "String stuff"
```

[Here is the documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp).

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell replace() to repeat the regex:

```
.replace(/ /g,'')
```

The g character means to repeat the search through the entire string. Read about this, and other RegEx modifiers available in JavaScript [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

If you want to match all whitespace, and not just the literal space character, use \s as well:

```
.replace(/\s/g,'')
```

Comment: This will remove spaces in the middle, I don't think he wants that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.trim()` to remove the unneeded whitespaces on either side of the `textContent` string like so:

```
// "(lots of spaces) String stuff (lots of spaces)"
document.querySelector('.title h2').textContent

// Add .trim() to get "String stuff"
document.querySelector('.title h2').textContent.trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex for this; you can simply use **[`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)**:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.title h2').textContent.trim());
```

```html
<div class="title">
 <h2>   Some stuff    </h2>
</div>
```

If you really want to use a regex, you can use **[`.replace(/\s+/, '')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.title h2').textContent;
const output = input.replace(/\s+/, '');

console.log(output);
```

```html
<div class="title">
 <h2>   Some stuff    </h2>
</div>
```